# How to set Null to the related table record on soft delete in Laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel.

I have two tables related to each other.

I want to set null to the related table record when the other related table record is soft deleted.

I know how to soft delete when the other related table record, but how can I set null instead of soft-delete?

## Product Model (Edited)

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $table = "products";

    public function projects()
    {

        return $this->hasMany("App\Model\Project");

    }


    public static function boot(){

        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($product)
        {

            //set null
            $product->projects()->setNull();

        });

    }

}
```

## Project Model(Edited)

```
<?php

    class Project extends Model
    {
        use SoftDeletes;
        protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

        public function product()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo("App\Model\Product");

        }

        public function setNull()
        {

            $this->product_id = NULL;
            $this->save();

        }

    }
```

## Table Schema

```
        Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('project_name')->unique("project_name");
            $table->integer('project_value')->unsigned();


            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete("set null");

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        });
```

## note

one project belongs to one product. It seems a bit weird but it's ok.

## Error Message

When I delete a product record, I got the following error.

```
[2017-05-13 17:25:28] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setNull() in /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2443
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1239): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('setNull', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('setNull', Array)
#2 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(340): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /vagrant/door/app/Model/Product.php(44): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->__call('setNull', Array)
#4 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(348): App\Model\Product::App\Model\{closure}(Object(App\Model\Product))
#5 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}('eloquent.delete...', Array)
#6 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(172): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('eloquent.delete...', Array, false)
#7 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php(148): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('eloquent.delete...', Object(App\Model\Product))
#8 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(748): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fireModelEvent('deleted', false)
#9 /vagrant/door/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php(80): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->delete()
#10 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ProductController->destroy(Object(App\Http\Requests\ProductRequest), '1')
```

Comment: Define a custom method in your project model which sets its fields to NULL then call the function inside boot method like `$product->projects()->setNull()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`dissociate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) method, this will reset both the foreign key of the relation and the relation on the object.

Basically you want something like this:

```
static::deleted(function($product)
{
    // remove relation
    $product->projects()->each(function($project) {
        $project->product()->dissociate();
        $project->save();
    });
});
```

Comment: If I dissociate, I don't need to set null any more?

Comment: Thanks! it became null after sissociating.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971754/badmethodcallexception-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-build

Answer (score 0):

In your project model define a custom method like,

```
 public function setNull() 
{
 $this->field_names= NULL; 
$this->save(); 
}
```

Then in the boot function you call this method like

```
$product->projects()->setNull();
```

*P. S- sorry I'm on mobile*

Comment: the foreign key is "product_id". In this case, "$this->field_names= NULL" should be "$this->product_id= NULL" ?

Comment: @Hayatomo yes. Try that see

Comment: 2017-05-13 17:25:28] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setNull() in /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2443
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1239): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('setNull', Array)