# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel.

This is what I'm trying to do.

When building record is deleted, the related room record is deleted as well. In addition to that, when the related room record is deleted on building record being deleted, I want to set null to the foreign key to room id on the related visit_records record.

When I try to detach the relationship between room model record and visitingRecord model record, it causes an error.

How can I make it work??

> Building => Room => VisitingRecord
>
> Building has many rooms. Room belongs to a building.  Room has many
>   visit records.  Visit Record belongs to a room.

## Building Model Class

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class Building extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $table = "buildings";



    public function rooms()
    {

        return $this->hasMany("App\Model\Room");

    }


    public static function boot(){

        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($building)
        {

            //This 4 lines cause an error.

            $building->rooms()->each(function($room) {
                $room->visitRecords()->detach();
                $room->save();
            });

            //this line is ok.
            $building->rooms()->delete();


        });

    }






}
```

## log

```
[2017-05-15 13:36:02] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach() in /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2451
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(1250): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->__call('detach', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('detach', Array)
#2 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(340): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /vagrant/door/app/Model/Building.php(62): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->__call('detach', Array)
#4 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(56): App\Model\Building::App\Model\{closure}(Object(App\Model\Room), 0)
#5 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(35): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Concerns\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection))
#6 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(60): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->chunk(1000, Object(Closure))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->each(Object(Closure))
#8 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php(340): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /vagrant/door/app/Model/Building.php(64): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->__call('each', Array)
#10 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(348): App\Model\Building::App\Model\{closure}(Object(App\Model\Building))
#11 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(199): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}('eloquent.delete...', Array)
#12 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(172): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('eloquent.delete...', Array, false)
#13 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php(148): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->fire('eloquent.delete...', Object(App\Model\Building))
#14 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(754): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fireModelEvent('deleted', false)
#15 /vagrant/door/app/Http/Controllers/BuildingController.php(274): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->delete()
#16 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\BuildingController->destroy('2', Object(App\Http\Requests\BuildingRequest))
#17 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('destroy', Array)
#19 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\BuildingController), 'destroy')
#20 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#21 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(559): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#22 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(561): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#43 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(520): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(498): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /vagrant/door/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Debugbar.php(51): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Debugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#52 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#55 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#57 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#58 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#61 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#62 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#63 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#64 /vagrant/door/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 /vagrant/door/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detach used in **many-to-many** relation. 
Change `->detach()` to `->update(['room_id' = null])` and make sure the **room_id** column is **nullable**

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it now! room_id column is set to be nullable already.

Comment: Thank you so much!